# Solved: How to combine tf.gradients with tf.data.dataset and keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a workflow that uses `tf.data.dataset` batches and an iterator. For performance reasons, I am really trying to avoid using the placeholder->feed_dict loop workflow.

The process I'm trying to implement involves grad-cam (which requires the gradient of the loss with respect to the final convolutional layer of a CNN) as an intermediate step, and ideally I'd like to be able to try it out on several Keras pre-trained models, including non-sequential ones like ResNet.

Most implementations of grad-cam that I've found rely on hand-crafting the CNN of interest in tensorflow. I found one implementation, https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-grad-cam, that is made for keras models, and following that example, I get

```
def safe_norm(x):
    return x / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(x ** 2) + 1e-8)
vgg_ = VGG19()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))

#preprocessing...

it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

files, batch = it.get_next()
conv5_4 = vgg_.layers[-6]
h_k, w_k, c_k = conv5_4.output.shape[1:]

vgg_model = Model(inputs=vgg_.input, outputs=vgg_.output)
conv_model = Model(inputs=vgg_.input, outputs=conv5_4.output)
probs = vgg_model(batch)
predicted_class = tf.argmax(probs, axis=-1)

layer_name = 'block5_conv4'
target_layer = lambda x: target_category_loss(x, predicted_class, n_categories)
x = Lambda(target_layer)(vgg_model.outputs[0])
model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs[0], outputs=x)

loss = K.sum(model.output, axis=-1)
conv_output =  [l for l in model.layers if l.name is layer_name][0].output
grads = Lambda(safe_norm)(K.gradients(loss, [conv_output])[0])
gradient_function = K.function([model.input], [conv_output, grads])

output, grads_val = gradient_function([batch])
weights = tf.reduce_mean(grads_val, axis = (1, 2))
cam = tf.ones([batch_size, h_k, w_k], dtype = tf.float32)

cam += tf.reduce_sum(output * tf.reshape(weights, [-1, 1, 1, weights.shape[-1]]), axis=-1)

cam = tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_images(images=tf.expand_dims(cam, axis=-1), size=(224, 224)))
cam = tf.maximum(cam, 0)
heatmap = cam / tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(cam, axis=[1, 2]), shape=[-1, 1, 1])
```

The problem is that `gradient_function([batch])` returns a numpy array whose value is determined by the first batch, so that `heatmap` doesn't change with subsequent evaluations.

I've tried replacing `K.function` with a `Model` in various ways, but nothing seems to work. I usually end up either with an error suggesting that `grads` evaluates to `None` or that one model or another is expecting a feed_dict and not receiving one.

Is this code salvageable? Is there a better way to do this besides looping through the data several times (once to get all the grad-cams and then again once I have them) or using placeholders and feed_dicts?

Edit:

```
def safe_norm(x):
    return x / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(x ** 2) + 1e-8)
vgg_ = VGG19()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))

#preprocessing...

it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

files, batch = it.get_next()
conv5_4 = vgg_.layers[-6]
h_k, w_k, c_k = conv5_4.output.shape[1:]

vgg_model = Model(inputs=vgg_.input, outputs=vgg_.output)
conv_model = Model(inputs=vgg_.input, outputs=conv5_4.output)
probs = vgg_model(batch)
predicted_class = tf.argmax(probs, axis=-1)

layer_name = 'block5_conv4'
target_layer = lambda x: target_category_loss(x, predicted_class, n_categories)
x = Lambda(target_layer)(vgg_model.outputs[0])
model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs[0], outputs=x)

loss = K.sum(model.output, axis=-1)
conv_output =  [l for l in model.layers if l.name is layer_name][0].output
grads = Lambda(safe_norm)(K.gradients(loss, [conv_output])[0])
gradient_function = K.function([model.input], [conv_output, grads])

output, grads_val = gradient_function([batch])
weights = tf.reduce_mean(grads_val, axis = (1, 2))
cam = tf.ones([batch_size, h_k, w_k], dtype = tf.float32)

cam += tf.reduce_sum(output * tf.reshape(weights, [-1, 1, 1, weights.shape[-1]]), axis=-1)

cam = tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_images(images=tf.expand_dims(cam, axis=-1), size=(224, 224)))
cam = tf.maximum(cam, 0)
heatmap = cam / tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(cam, axis=[1, 2]), shape=[-1, 1, 1])

# other operations on heatmap and batch ...

# ...

output_function = K.function(model.input, [node1, ..., nodeN])

for batch in range(n_batches):
    outputs1, ... , outputsN = output_function(batch)
```

Gives me the desired outputs for each batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `K.function` returns numpy arrays because it evaluates the symbolic computation in your graph. What I think you should do is to keep everything symbolic up to `K.function`, and after getting the gradients, perform all computations of the Grad-CAM weights and final saliency map using numpy.

Then you can iterate on your dataset, evaluate `gradient_function` on a new batch of data, and compute the saliency map.

If you want to keep everything symbolic, then you should not use `K.function` to produce the gradient function, but use the symbolic gradient (the output of  `K.gradient`, without lambda) and convolutional feature maps (`conv_output`) and perform the saliency map computation on top of that, and then build a function (using `K.function`) that takes the model input, and outputs the saliency map.

Hope the explanation is enough.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I needed to get rid of K.function at that step to keep things symbolic for the other calculations post-grad-cam, but it didn't occur to me to use it farther down and include the other output nodes as outputs instead of sess.run(...)